# Need help in constructing JSON Payload in DataWeave 2.0

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I have 2 below input payloads which I need to use to construct payload # 3 as shown below. The payload # 2 is meta data information for all the fields.

**Payload # 1:**

> The fields in this payload change for every employee, the below
> payload has only 2 fields

---

```
{
  "employee": [
    {
      "Employee_Number": "123456",
      "Country_of_Birth": "USA",
    }
  ]
}
```

**Payload # 2:**

> (this holds meta data kind of information which needs to be referred
> from  payload # 3 for constructing the payload # 3). For instance, for
> the Employee_Number from payload # 1, the meta data info needs to
> pulled from Payload # 2 and for all the other respective fields from
> payload # 1 accordingly.

---

```
[
  {
    "employeeMetaColumn": "Employee_Number",
    "employeeMetaText": "Employee Number",
    "employeeMetaType": "SECT",
    "employeeMetaId": 435
  },
  {
    "employeeMetaColumn": "Country_of_Birth",
    "employeeMetaText": "Country of Birth",
    "employeeMetaType": "SECT",
    "employeeMetaId": 345
  },
  {
    "employeeMetaColumn": "Years_Completed",
    "employeeMetaText": "Years Completed",
    "employeeMetaType": "FLD",
    "employeeMetaId": 427
  },
  {
    "employeeMetaColumn": "First_Name",
    "employeeMetaText": "First Name",
    "employeeMetaType": "SECT",
    "employeeMetaId": 998
  }
]
```

**Payload # 3**

> Final payload to be constructed

---

{

```
"parameters": [{
        "employeeParamValue": [
            "123456"
        ],
        "employeeMetaColumn": "Employee_Number",
        "employeeMetaText": "Employee Number",
        "employeeMetaType": "SECT",
        "employeeMetaId": 435,
        
    },
    {
        "employeeParamValue": [
            "USA"
        ],
        "employeeMetaColumn": "Country_of_Birth",
        "employeeMetaText": "Country of Birth",
        "employeeMetaType": "SECT"
        "employeeMetaId": 345,
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is ambiguous however I made an educated guess that the results that don't map to a value in payload1 should be filtered out from the output. The rest is just mapping the value in each `employeeMetaColumn` to a value in `payload1`. I had also to assume that the array `payload1.employee` has size 1. In my script `payload` contains the value of `payload2` and `payload1` is a variable.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var payload1={
  "employee": [
    {
      "Employee_Number": "123456",
      "Country_of_Birth": "USA",
    }
  ]
}
---
payload 
    map {
        employeeParamValue: [payload1.employee[0][$.employeeMetaColumn]],
        ($)
    }
    filter ($.employeeParamValue[0] != null)
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "employeeParamValue": [
      "123456"
    ],
    "employeeMetaColumn": "Employee_Number",
    "employeeMetaText": "Employee Number",
    "employeeMetaType": "SECT",
    "employeeMetaId": 435
  },
  {
    "employeeParamValue": [
      "USA"
    ],
    "employeeMetaColumn": "Country_of_Birth",
    "employeeMetaText": "Country of Birth",
    "employeeMetaType": "SECT",
    "employeeMetaId": 345
  }
]
```

I don't understand why `employeeParamValue` is an array. It doesn't seem to make much sense since it has to be a single value.